# control-nav and positioning

Tags: flexslider

I am trying to position the control nav in flexslider 2 (the dots for each slide).  Default is text-align:center.  If you change to the left it positions to the left no problem.  If you change to right then while it positions to the right it also shows text numbers of each slide over each dot.

How can I position this to the right WITHOUT the text numbers showing up?  Furthermore, why are they showing up when aligned to the right?

You can see this happen out of the box in its default state by just changing the value to the below.

```
/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;  text-align: right;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing width allows positioning without the number issue

Answer (score 1):

I thought that changing the -9999px to a positive had worked for me, until I realized that it just pushed the text way off the screen. But you could still scroll to it. My fix, leave the text-indent at -9999px; and add 
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); .

The last 0 in this controls the alpha, and with it at 0, that makes the numbers completely invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this, removing the `width` doesn't work. Here is a solution that does work:

```
.flex-control-nav {
   text-align: right;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
    text-indent: 9999px;
}
```

When aligning the control nav to the right, you need to change the text indent from negative -9999px to a positive 9999px.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to adjust the positioning without the numbers.

```
/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {position: absolute; bottom: 25px; right: 20px;}
```